# Accessing values in a 2D array incorrectly

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have a 2D array such as:

```
        // construct initial **array
        int **arr;
        arr = new int* [SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[SIZE];
        }
```

I am then filling the array with input from cin, and that is working fine. Yet when I go to access the values in the array by double for loop iteration, I get the incorrect values.

I have printed out the values as I am adding them in something like:

```
"Adding <int> to array position <row><col>"
```

For example, I am storing the ints `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,0}}`, yet when I go to access them, I get the values `{{49,50,51}, {52,53,54}, {55,56,48}}`.

I have a feeling that it's something trivial, I just have no idea where to look.

Comment: How do you input your values? Without this we can't know what is wrong.

Comment: @Tyler Bell: Can you post the code where you add values to `arr`?

Comment: The text representations of numbers aren't the same thing as the numerical values of those numbers. See Mark's answer below. (49 is the ASCII value for the character "1", and so on)

Comment: @MarkByers was correct, indeed. I feel stupid. Thank you, all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are storing the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of the numbers rather than their numeric values, for example the character `1` has ASCII value 49. Check that the variable you are using to read input is a numeric type and not `char`.

Comment: Wow, you are 100% correct. I am looking at my code, and I completely forgot to convert the characters into their integer values. Thank you very much, I feel like a complete n00b.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're getting the ASCII values of the characters -- ie, 49 is '1', 50 is '2', etc.

Comment: hah, see Mark answered just before me :) This is one of those cases where having an an incrementing value as a test case is helpful; you'll see patterns like this, regardless of whether it's hex, binary flags, ASCII, etc.